# How do I read a double column from MySQL and assign it to a C# double variable?

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a problem while reading my DataBase.
Until now I was sure that when I read some doubles from MySQL (they are stored as doubles **not as strings / varchar**), they are returned with a dot as decimal separator. (10.5). But now I notice that in fact, they are returned with a coma?

I lately created a new table (one month ago), but just now I noticed that its double values are returned with a comma `,` instead of the dot `.`.

I checked and the tables are all in uff8_unicode_ci.

I don't understand because I was sure that `,` could not be used in MySQL, also checked that on that [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6627239/insert-non-english-decimal-points-in-mysql/6627551#6627551).

**Nota** : This is maybe due to the fact that I use several computers for tests, some are in French, some in Russian?

Edit :

To edit the table I do the following :

```
string request = "UPDATE [vegasteel].consumables SET ID_MACHINE=" + this.idMachine + ",GROUPE="PLASMA",TYPE=\'\',DETAIL=\'14\',SPEED=10.5,TIME=5.5,COST=0.5 WHERE ID=" + this.id;
DataBase.Update(request);
```

Then to read it :

```
if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
{
    IDataReader dataReader = ExecuteReader(query);
    while (dataReader.Read())
    {
        Consumable consumable = new Consumable();
        consumable.ID = Convert.ToInt64(dataReader["ID"].ToString());
        consumable.IdMachine = Convert.ToInt64(dataReader["ID_MACHINE"].ToString());
        consumable.Groupe = dataReader["GROUPE"].ToString();
        consumable.Type = dataReader["TYPE"].ToString();
        consumable.Detail = dataReader["DETAIL"].ToString();
        if(consumable.Groupe=="PLASMA")
        {
            string toto = "";
        }
        consumable.Speed = Global.ConvertToDouble(dataReader["SPEED"].ToString());
        consumable.Time = Global.ConvertToDouble(dataReader["TIME"].ToString());
        consumable.Cost = Global.ConvertToDouble(dataReader["COST"].ToString());
        list.Add(consumable);
    }
    this.CloseConnection();
}
```

the `Global.ConvertToDouble` is a function I made to add a comma or a dot regarding the current culture. But the problem is when I read it, dataReader["COST"] equals `0,5`, and not `0.5`

**Edit 2 :**

As asked, here is Global.ConvertToDouble function, but as I explained the problem is before that function, as comma is sent instead of dot to the function.

```
public static double ConvertToDouble(this string strToParse, char decimalSymbol = '.')
{
    if (strToParse.Contains('E'))
    {
        strToParse = "0";
    }
    string tmp = Regex.Match(strToParse, @"([-]?[0-9]+)([\s])?([0-9]+)?[." + decimalSymbol + "]?([0-9 ]+)?([0-9]+)?").Value;

    if (tmp.Length > 0 && strToParse.Contains(tmp))
    {
        var currDecSeparator = System.Windows.Forms.Application.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator;

        tmp = tmp.Replace(".", currDecSeparator).Replace(decimalSymbol.ToString(), currDecSeparator);
        return double.Parse(tmp);
    }

    return double.NegativeInfinity;
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201177/discussion-on-question-by-siegfried-v-how-do-i-read-a-double-column-from-mysql-a).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# doubles show comma instead of period](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518625/c-sharp-doubles-show-comma-instead-of-period)

Comment: @nl-x The problem was for reading MySQL doubles. In fact the problem was just I did it the wrong way (using ToString). But doing as tymtam wrote, this solved the problem. I also rewrote all of my code modifying it also for bool, int and longs, as I just did it not correctly from the beginning...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should **not** be converting the columns to string and then parsing them. You should read them directly as the type they are.

```
consumable.Speed = (double) dataReader["SPEED"];
```

or

```
consumable.Speed = Convert.ToDouble(dataReader["SPEED"]);
```

#### Note on `null` handling

*(Thanks @mjwills for mentioning this)*

The results from the db may contain null values and there are many ways of handling nulls in results with `IDataReader` (you can see [SQL Data Reader - handling Null column values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1772025/sql-data-reader-handling-null-column-values) or [Null safe way to get values from an IDataReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609875/null-safe-way-to-get-values-from-an-idatareader) or search the broader web).

For example you will need to decide if you want `null` or default value (0 for `double`) when the return value is null.

To get you started here's a helper method (which can easily be changed into a extension method, and maybe even made generic so that you can deal with `int`s and other types).

```
public static double GetNotNullExample(IDataReader reader, string colName, double valueIfNull)
{
    var colIndex = reader.GetOrdinal(colName);
    if (!reader.IsDBNull(colIndex))
        return reader.GetDouble(colIndex);
    else
        return valueIfNull;
}
```

---

## What's happening

After you reinstalled your computer the culture has changed. The following snippet shows the impact of the culture on the `ToString` method.

```
double pie = 3.14; // ;)

CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US", false);
Console.WriteLine(pie.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(pie.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("ru-RU", false);
Console.WriteLine(pie.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(pie.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

### Output

```
3.14
3.14
3,14
3.14
```

### But I still want to `ToString()` and then parse

1. Don't.
2. If you were to continue ToString()->Parse approach, you would have to ensure that ToString is called with `InvariantCuture`.

```
consumable.Speed = Global.ConvertToDouble(dataReader["SPEED"]
                   .ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Comment: @tymtam thanks, didn't even see the end of your answer, but very clear even for me :)